# external Host Small Files (20 MB size) with high bandwidth and 100k downloader - alternatives

Tags: javascript, angular, web, hosting, bandwidth

I have an angular application with javascript bundle, images, pdf, docx (size of 10MB)
the number of users who will download those files are 100k, unfortunately, most of those users are concurrent. so there is a total download of 1TB from the website which make it very slow.
my issue is with the big number of concurrent users.

i want to use external file hosting so the website can run faster.

I need To know what is the best (cost-bandwidth) alternative file hosting.

and if there any file hosting to just serve raw files.

**update**
i already did some steps to enhance performance----->
-using gzipper to compress files.
-seperated the application into smaller modules.

- use lazy loading for most of contents like images, javascript bundles.
  my issue is with the big number of concurrent users

Comment: Why are you serving 10MB images in the first place? Maybe try to reduce the file sizes?

Comment: i can compress them and reduce quality, my issue is with the big number of concurrent users;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CDN servers like cloudfront, Cloudfare which are nowadays cheap and best for concurrent users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have also same concurrent users in my application. So, I tried the same and worth to use as well efficiency.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Which plan is the most suitable for my situation?